# How to make PMD run at the start of the maven build rather than at the end of it?

Tags: java, maven, build, pom.xml, pmd

I have the following configuration within my pom.xml that checks for PMD violations:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${pmd.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
        <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
        <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
        <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
                <goal>cpd-check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I run a build using the command `mvn clean install`, the PMD checks are run as last step of the build process. Rather, I would want the PMD checks to run as the first step of the build.

Does anybody know how could I achieve this?

Comment: specify another phase in execution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your answers @JamesB and @PetrMensik for letting me know about the *phase* element within the POM. It helped me solve my problem. I finally settled for this:

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${pmd.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
    <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

I used the phase:*compile*, the reason being I have plenty of tests in my project which take up a lot of time to execute. And, its quite irritating to wait for those tests to finish and be notified about a PMD violation at the end of all the tests. I needed something just before the tests. Hence, I settled for ***compile***.

Further suggestions are welcome. :)

Comment: The trouble with using `compile` is that you already have a plugin bound to that, and the execution order will be determined by the order the plugins appear in the POM - not ideal. Moreover, you won't be able to run PMD on any code generated in the `generate-test-sources` phase, which might not matter to you, but obviously isn't great as a general solution.

Might I suggest the `process-test-sources` phase? That way, you have all your code, and you know it compiles, but you haven't had to run your tests yet.

Also, it would be polite to accept someone else's answer rather than your own.

Answer (score 7):

Add the phase element to your POM.

```
<plugin>
<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
<version>${pmd.version}</version>
<configuration>
    <linkXRef>true</linkXRef>
    <sourceEncoding>UTF-8</sourceEncoding>
    <minimumTokens>100</minimumTokens>
    <targetJdk>1.7</targetJdk>
</configuration>
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
</plugin>
```

The validate phase is the first phase of the maven lifecycle: http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html

Answer (score 2):

You need to hook execution of this plugin to a different Maven lifecycle phase (`validation` comes as the first one in default lifecycle).

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>check</goal>
            <goal>cpd-check</goal>
        </goals>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

See this the [list](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html#Plugins) of the available Maven phases for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I set build configuration

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-pmd-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${pmd.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnViolation>true</failOnViolation>
                <printFailingErrors>true</printFailingErrors>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>check</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```